# Slf4J/Log4J: How to use a new output file for each logger where the file name is known during runtime?

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2, slf4j

I have the following scenario:

I am converting a bunch of files and need to log each conversion. The output shall be stored alongside the converted and original file. My plan is to create/get a logger from the `LoggerFactory` with the file name as ID (the class name is not suitable since it will always be `Converter.class`). Therefore each logger returned is unique. Then, I want each logger to have a file appender to the log file. This info is available only at runtime since only then I know which files the user wants to convert and where they shall be stored in. Ideally, everything is configured in some config file so I don't have to bother my code with wrappers and stuff and can simply use Slf4J.

So, is there a way to get the logger's name (will be some path) within the config file and pass that as the output file to the appender?

Answer (score 0):

This may sound strange but I would suggest using the RollingFileAppender with a custom triggering policy and the DirectWriteRolloverStrategy. Your custom triggering policy would always return false in the isTriggeringEvent method. Instead, you would call a method in the triggering policy that just does `manager.rollover()`.

Then in the filePattern attribute you would specify the pattern for the file name you want to use. You can use any Log4j Lookup in the name (with 2 dollar sign characters). So you could put the ID in the ThreadContext and use `$${mdc:ID}` to get it or create a custom Lookup. In that case you don't have to mess with the Logger name - just log like you normally would.

As an example, your lAppender configuration might look like:

```
<RollingFile name="Rolling" filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/$${mdc:ID}.log" createOnDemand="true">
  <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <MyTriggeringPolicy>
</RollingFile>
```

Then your application would read your configuration file and store the name of the first file to be converted by doing `ThreadContext.put("ID", name);`. When it finishes with that file and wants to proceed to the next it would store the next name in the ThreadContext and then call the custom triggering policy to perform a rollover.

Comment: What will the file name be like? My requirement is that the log file must be named as the converted file. Can such a file appender and rollover strategy be set up in a config file?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: It totally seems to be the right direction. I'll give it a shot once the basic stuff works. Thank you a lot!

Comment: It functions so far, but the file is named completely wrong. The pattern with $$ is not replaced.

```
<Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="DynamicFile" filePattern="$${ctx:LOG_FILE}-CONVERTED.log" createOnDemand="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd} - %msg%n" />
            <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy />
            <Policies>
                <MyTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="DynamicFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
```

Comment: MyTriggeringPolicy.java looks like this:
```
@org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin(name = "MyTriggeringPolicy", category = "Core", printObject = true)
public class MyTriggeringPolicy implements TriggeringPolicy {
  @Override
  public void initialize(RollingFileManager manager) {
    manager.rollover();
  }


  @Override
  public boolean isTriggeringEvent(LogEvent logEvent) {
    return false;
  }

  @PluginFactory
  public static MyTriggeringPolicy createPolicy() {
    return new MyTriggeringPolicy();
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no formating in the comment section I fear. :(

Comment: Did you set the value of LOG_FILE in the ThreadContext before logging was initialized? For your use case I don't think calling manager.rollover during initialization is a good idea. Your triggering policy needs a method you can call that will cause the rollover to occur whenever you want it to.

Comment: Yes, I had.
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
ThreadContext.put("LOG_FILE", file.getFileName().toString());
logger.info("CONVERSION STARTED");